# How load custom .net dll with accoreconsole.exe in Design Automation with all AutoCAD DLL's

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have created a AutoCAD custom .net dll for the desktop version which had some operation.

1. Adding multiple empty drawing documents.
2. Opening the existing drawing document and copying the required blocks in the newly created drawing document.
3. Performing some operation on them, discarding all the unnecessary drawing documents and saving one of them as an output drawing document.

I had a query regarding opening the existing document and adding the empty document using Design Automation API but I couldn't achieve it with Design Automation.
As I explored I found that only AcCoreMgd.dll and AcDbMgd.dl are allowed with accoreconsole.exe.
[Load custom .net dll inside accoreconsole.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262545/load-custom-net-dll-inside-accoreconsole-exe)

DLL's used by AutoCAD custom .net project for desktop version are (AcCoreMgd.dll,AcCui.dll,AcDbMgd.dll,AcMgd.dll,AcTcMgd.dll,AdUIMgd.dll)

I wanted to use all the above DLL's with Design Automation for AutoCAD.
Will you please let us know how we can use desktop versions like support in Design Automation for AutoCAD?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add other modules when working with Design Automation or AccCoreConsole. Please note AcCoreConsole is a Headless part of AutoCAD in other words no UI libraries are permitted. Following are the libaries that a crx app should bind.

Where XX - module version of AutoCAD release [for more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD_version_history)
If you are developing a .NET module, you need to use following [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoCAD.NET.Core/24.1.51000)

```
ac1stXX.lib
acdbXX.lib
acdbmgd.lib
AcDbPointCloudObj.lib
acgeXX.lib
acgiapi.lib
acismobjXX.lib
AcMPolygonObjXX.lib
AcSceneOE.lib
axdb.lib
rxapi.lib
acbrXX.lib
acgexXX.lib
AdImaging.lib
AdIntImgServices.lib
AecModeler.lib
AsdkHlrApiXX.lib
acapp_crx.lib
AcCamera.lib
accore.lib
AcFdEval.lib
AcPublish_crx.lib
```

Why do you need to open mutilple documents ?, you can insert multiple blocks from different drawings in to Host drawing. Make modifications, save and send to your Server.